# discord.js checking if a DM went through and sending a message if it did or not

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

im making a command that rickrolls people in dms and currently it sends the message "could not rickroll the user" if it could not message that person, but does not send a message that it successfully rickrolled the user because i could not figure out how to do that

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');

module.exports = class RickrollCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('rickroll', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member to rickroll.');
    if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send('The user mentioned is not in the server.');

    const rickrollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("You've Been Rickrolled!")
    .setThumbnail('https://i1.wp.com/my-thai.org/wp-content/uploads/rick-astley.png?resize=984%2C675&ssl=1')
    .setFooter('Rick astley sends his regards')
    .setColor('#FFA500');

      await mentionedMember.send('https://tenor.com/view/dance-moves-dancing-singer-groovy-gif-17029825')
    await mentionedMember.send(
      rickrollEmbed
    ).catch(async err => message.channel.send("i was unable to rickroll the user."));
  }
}
```

the problem is that it catches the error and sends the message "i was unable to rickroll the user" but if it does successfully message the user i want it to send "Successfully rickrolled the user" and i couldnt figure out how to do that.

Comment: You either use `async/await + try/catch` or `then/catch`, no need to use both

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you can simply add a `then()` when your "promise" is fulfilled. This ties into how `async/await` functions work. For more info you could check out various other resources online, just a quick google search will do.

To add the `then()` method into your code, I'd suggest:

```js
//THEN METHOD HERE
.then(() => {
    message.channel.send("Successfully rickrolled the user.");
})
//CATCH METHOD HERE TO CHECK FOR REJECTED PROMISES
.catch(err => { //no need to use the async
    message.channel.send('I was unable to rickroll the user.');
});
```

Comment: I did what @PerplexingParadox told me to do yet it still doesn't send a message saying "I was unable to rickroll the user." when the mentioned user has their dms closed, also another problem im having is when i try to mention the user using their ID it doesn't work and sends a message saying The user mentioned is not in the server.

Comment: Make sure to add the `then()` method for the first message you're sending to. I'm not sure how much it would affect it.

From your code it seems like that you have to ping the user (not use the ID) for the command to work as seen by the `if (!mentionedMember)` statement.